# Patterns used for accessing geolocation API

Tags: javascript, react.js

Here's how I'm using my location component:

```
<LocationContainer opts={{timeout: 5000}}> 
    {(address, error) => {
        if (error) {
            return <div>Could not determine address (why...?  <span style={{color: 'red'}}>{error.message}</span>)</div>
        } else if (address) {
            return <div>{address.neighbourhood}, {address.city}</div>
        } else {
            return <div>loading...</div>
        }
    }}
</LocationContainer>
```

And here is the component itself:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class LocationContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            address: null, 
            error: null,
        };
    }

    getLocation(opts) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, opts);
            } else {
                reject('geolocation not supported');
            }
        });
    }

    async getAddress(opts) {
        let location = await this.getLocation(opts);       
        let resp = await axios.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse', {
            params: {
                lat: location.coords.latitude,
                lon: location.coords.longitude,
                format: 'json',
            },
        });
        return resp.data.address;
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            let address = await this.getAddress(this.props.opts);
            this.setState({address: address});
        } catch (error) {
            this.setState({error: error})
        }
    }

    render() {
        return this.props.children(this.state.address, this.state.error);
    }
}

export default LocationContainer;
```

The code renders the location of the client, or an error message is displayed if it can't be found.

I have two main questions:

- Is what I've done a sensible way to integrate the geolocation API into a react website?
- Does the usage of `LocationContainer` make sense to an experienced react developer?

Would love feedback on any anti-patterns or general react coding style.

Comment: Hi Ferguzz, welcome to CodeReview. To Close Voters, please comment as to why.